# First Text Game : print line replicates

Tags: java

Its my first project that helped me learn Java. Game looks good but i need to get input check if it for sure Integer etc.When I tried to check it with Int but this "print line" prints itself again after doing function it have to do after print.I'm asking for your understanding because I am just learning it (started this week).

I am talking about this part:

```
            if(scanner.hasNextInt()){
            choiceStr1=scanner.next();
            choice_1= Integer.parseInt(choiceStr1);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println(input);
            space = enterScanner.nextLine();
            townGateRevisited();
        }
```

Full code:

https://pastebin.com/rc5Mcef4

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your exact problem... Are you trying to make sure your input is a number? You could check that with Character.isDigit(). Mind that it's for single digits only. Please edit your question to be so specific as possible. Perhaps adding your output now, and your desired output? Also, if your choiceStr1 isn't a number, then Integer.parseInt() will throw an exception

Comment: I want to check if input is int and if it isnt send it to point when code started.I want to do something similars with others inputs. https://imgur.com/a/IbEQ3I4 <-- what i am talking about exacly

Comment: Then you would need to put your code in a loop (do-while, or while) and checking for correct input, could indeed be with scanner.nextInt() surrounded with a try-catch

Comment: which code? rest of class? I dont understand good enough try catch but i will learn it today

Comment: I added `while(choiceStr1==scanner.nextInt())` for rest of code (switch and those ifs ) but it didnt changed anything

Comment: I've provided a basic answer you might want to try. I'm signing off for the weekend, but don't hesitate to comment. I check StackOverflow daily during the week.

Answer (score 0):

To check if user input is integer , just use `scanner.nextInt();` method in `try` block than catch `InputMismatchException` if it is not int.

```java
try{
   int choiceStr1=scanner.nextInt();
}catch(InputMismatchException e){
   //do something here, this block will be skipped if user input is int 
}
```

Comment: Same thing happend. In catch i added                                                                                                                                              
            `System.out.println(input);
            space = enterScanner.nextLine();
            townGateRevisited();`

Comment: Why do you need ```enterScanner.nextLine();```? Do you need integer for this input? Or you are trying to do other stuff if user types non-decimal in ```choiceStr1```?

Comment: without this "space button" print line loop

Comment: i want to get int but i dont get it from enterScanner there.I get it from this .nextInt()

Answer (score 0):

I'm giving you a very basic example I coded myself whilst learning the language for the first time. Mind you, it's very basic and there are other ways! But this should do fine to show you how to loop, while checking if your input's correct

```
public class MyApplication { 

public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String enteredNumber = "";
        do {
            System.out.println("enter a number");
            enteredNumber = scan.nextLine();
        } while (!isNumber(enteredNumber));
    }

    private static boolean isNumber(String isNumber) {
        for (int i = 0; i < isNumber.length(); i++) {
            if (!isDigit(isNumber.charAt(i))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static boolean isDigit(char isDigit) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (isDigit == i + 48) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This doesn't need a try-catch, and it uses the ascii-value for checking the input. Which is why I used a nextLine() instead of nextInt().

Happy coding, and keep asking questions/googling!